# How to set accepted values for angular route parameter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have to make two types of url: `/:culture` and `/:author`, where both have first-level url parameters. While culture is set of predefined parameters like `en`, `es`, `en-us`, `br`, `fr`, `it`, etc., author could be any username from db (except the names of cultures). So I wanna make the routing that could send user to `HomeCtrl` when param is in set of cultures and if not it would send him to `AuthorCtrl`. What could I do?

```
.when('/:culture/', {
    templateUrl:'partials/home/home',
    controller:'vvHomeCtrl'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define templateUrl and controller as functions and make this route like:

```
.when('/:cultureOrAuthor/', {
    templateUrl: function(params) {
        // AVAILABLE_CULTURES is your predefined array
        if(AVAILABLE_CULTURES.indexOf(params['cultureOrAuthor'])!==-1) {
            return 'urlForCultures';
        } else {
            return 'urlForAuthors';
        }
    },
    controller: function($scope, $routeParams) {
        if(AVAILABLE_CULTURES.indexOf($routeParams['cultureOrAuthor'])!==-1) {
            // first logic
        } else {
            // second logic
        }
    }
});
```

This is a good solution for simple controllers. Otherwise consider using resolve from router ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider)).

Answer (score 1):

I agree to @Mates solution by checking if the culture param is valid. Yet, I'd probably try to use the `redirectTo` property to separate the two route.

```
.when('/:culture/', {
    templateUrl:'partials/home/home',
    controller:'vvHomeCtrl',
    redirectTo:function(routeParams, path, search) {
        if(cultures.indexOf(routeParams.culture)!==-1) {
            //return path(string) to author route
        }
        return path;
    }
})
.when(/* Author route definition */);
```